# SQL query map values in multiple columns to different value in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a master table with 1000+ columns, of which many columns contain unique codes. The codes are mapped to values in another table. I am trying to produce a copy of the master table with the mapped values.

Master Table

```
id   name    cty    city   segment
==   ====    ===    ===    ===
01   John    001    012    081
02   Sam     001    019    110
03   Lee     005    029    110
```

Mapping Table

```
id   code    value
==   ====    ===
01   001     USA
02   012     San Francisco
03   019     New York City
04   005     Canada
05   029     Vancouver
06   081     Retail
07   110     Corporate
```

Output that I want:

```
id   name    cty     city            segment
==   ====    ===     ===             ===
01   John    USA     San Francisco   Retail
02   Sam     USA     New York City   Corporate
03   Lee     Canada  Vancouver       Corporate
```

Of course I could run many joins as follows:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, z1.value, z2.value, z3.value
FROM Master m
INNER JOIN mapping z1 ON m.cty = z1.code
INNER JOIN mapping z2 ON m.city = z2.code
INNER JOIN mapping z3 ON m.segment = z3.code
```

However, there are 100's of columns that are mapped to codes. Is there a SQL query that can achieve the same outcome or is cheaper to execute than writing multiple `INNER JOINS`?

The ideal outcome is that I can a run a simple `SELECT * FROM Master...` where I don't have to spell out each column, while having all the codes mapped to their respective values and at the same time I don't see the codes.

Comment: You can create VIEW . This would be one time effort to create query with required columns. And after that you simply need to select * from View

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot escape these hundreds of joins if your result set depends on it, but you can hide them from your client by means of saving them into a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createview.html):

Creating view

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT m.id, m.name, z1.value as city1, z2.value as city2, z3.value as segment
FROM Master m
INNER JOIN mapping z1 ON m.cty = z1.code
INNER JOIN mapping z2 ON m.city = z2.code
INNER JOIN mapping z3 ON m.segment = z3.code;
```

Querying view

```
SELECT * FROM my_view;
```

Views just execute a previously *saved* query and shows its results. But in case your query is too time consuming, you can create a so called `MATERIALIZED VIEW`. As the name suggests, it is physically created on disk and does not need to execute its origin query every time.

To [`create`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` just add `MATERIALIZED` to the statement

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS
SELECT ...
```

And to [`refresh`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) its values just do

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view;
```

Answer (score 0):

As apparently all values are strings (text, varchar) you can build a JSON key/value pair of the mapping and then access the keys dynamically.

I don't think that will be any faster (it might even be slower), but it only requires a single join and the names are dynamic.

```
select m.id, m.name, 
       mp.mappings ->> 'cty' as cty,
       mp.mappings ->> 'city' as city,
       mp.mappings ->> 'segment' as segment,
       mp.mappings as all_mappings
from master m
  left join lateral (
    select jsonb_object_agg(k, value) as mappings
    from mapping ma
      join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(m) - 'id' - 'name') as t(k,val)
        on ma.code = t.val
  ) mp on true
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9a277d6f800998109b080e65c5b91f1b)

`jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(m) - 'id' - 'name')` create a JSON value where the column names from the master table are the keys. The keys (=column names) `id` and `name` are removed from that JSON.

The values from there are then used to join against the mapping table. The result is the aggregated into a single JSON value where the column names from the master table are the keys and the values from the mapping table are the values.

There is no real way around specifying each output column individually. If you don't don't really need the individual columns you could just select `mp.mappings` and get all the values as a single JSON.